# No Launcher activity found google-play-services_lib

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to run google-play-services_lib on my galaxy s3, but I get this:

```
[2013-09-05 02:39:19 - google-play-services_lib] ------------------------------
[2013-09-05 02:39:19 - google-play-services_lib] Android Launch!
[2013-09-05 02:39:19 - google-play-services_lib] adb is running normally.
[2013-09-05 02:39:19 - google-play-services_lib] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-09-05 02:39:19 - google-play-services_lib] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-09-05 02:39:19 - google-play-services_lib] Performing sync
[2013-09-05 02:39:24 - google-play-services_lib] Uploading google-play-services_lib.apk onto device 'd20eb13c'
[2013-09-05 02:39:24 - google-play-services_lib] Installing google-play-services_lib.apk...
[2013-09-05 02:39:37 - google-play-services_lib] Installation error! The package already exists.
[2013-09-05 02:39:37 - google-play-services_lib] Launch canceled!
```

Does anyone know what I should do?  Thanks.

Comment: But why do you want to install Google play services again? Devices come with it by default.

Comment: you may be right... I'm simply trying to follow this guide:

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html

But actually I'm not sure about this step: 

2. Once you've installed the Google Play services package, the Google Maps sample is located in <android-sdk>/extras/google-play-services/samples/maps and shows you how to use the major components of the Google Maps Android APIs. 

Am I supposed to import that into eclipse and run it ?

Comment: You dont need to install google play services in device to run GoogleMap because all devices have it pre-installed.Yeah if you want to run it in Emulator then you need google play services to be installed there.

Comment: please see my updated answer on your emulator question. i hope, it's acceptable now.

Answer (score 2):

You can not run a library.
You need to include the library in your project and run that.

The google-play-services_lib is simply no app. So you can not run it like an app.

If you want to test google play service apps on an emulator, you need to pick the latest GoogleApi-18 avd image. It has google play services preinstalled.